# Generated UML Diagram from Android Kotlin project can't make associations (Intellij IDE)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, intellij-idea, uml

I have created a UML class diagram from my Android Kotlin project which worked fine. The diagram looks like this:
[image: Generated UML Diagram]

As you can see a lot of dependencies are already shown with the lines connecting the classes. Though I cannot get the simple associations between classes to work like for instance the relationship between MainActivity and MainViewModel doesn't show. Even though the MainActivity definitely has a property of the type MainViewModel. See image: [image: MainActivity with MainViewModel property]

When I try to use 'edge creation mode' to create the relation manually I get the following message: [Using 'edge creation mode' to create relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay24f.png)

Also when I try MainActivity: New -> Line to -> MainViewModel [image: See image] the same error message appears.

Comment: How could you generate diagram from kotlin?

Comment: @HamedRahimvand Using Intellij IDEA Ultimate, from kotlin you have to generate Java bytecode first to generate Diagram from.

Comment: Could you please file an issue to kotlin issue tracker https://kotl.in/issue and provide a project to reproduce?